# Angular 2+: Internet Explorer: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In Angular 4.2.4 (Angular-CLI 1.1.3), IE11 I get `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error` and `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference`. I have my polyfills in and I would have assumed that Webpack and Angular-CLI would have done the rest. What am I missing here?

`Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference` says after it: `bootstrap 50034e0a1f93dabcb117 (54, 1)` with no indication of a real filename. And `Syntax error` says it's in `vendor.bundle.js (63117,26)`, which looks like:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('click', suppressClick, true);
}, 0);
```

Update: Should have been more obvious to me before, but this looks like ES6 code, and it should be compiling down to ES5.

Comment: You are getting a syntax error and undefined variables but are not sharing any code.

Comment: Hi BBaysinger , I was getting same error try to delete the package.lock.json and npm install againg , worked for me

Comment: Are you starting your app with "ng serve" ? Are you using any JQuery code?

Comment: This could be one of a hundred problems. You might want to share a git repo since this is such a broad problem. As @AmericoArvani mentioned, it's likely to do with your npm installation or packages.

Comment: is it working in other browsers?

Comment: Try removing bundling from your webpack config and add source maps to see which file is breaking. It is hard to say without code

Comment: Try to give a timeout > 0

Comment: Would You mind checking the solution beneath if it answers Your question?

Comment: @Mark, it didn't fix it for me. I mentioned in my question that I had polyfills in already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2+: IE 11 Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911435/angular-2-ie-11-unable-to-get-property-call-of-undefined-or-null-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still running into this issue, try this:

[Angular 2+: IE 11 Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911435/angular-2-ie-11-unable-to-get-property-call-of-undefined-or-null-reference)

If the error you're getting occurs on a hunk of code that looks like this:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('click', suppressClick, true);
}, 0);
```

...then please let me know if the solution worked or not. I will update this answer, and possibly mark this question as duplicate.

I DO NOT BELIEVE THESE TO BE THE SAME ISSUE AT THIS TIME, AS THE ERRORS OCCURRED ON DIFFERENT CODE IN `bundle.js`. Someone voted this answer down, without giving any feedback on whether or not these questions have the same solution.

I do not have a way to test this currently, but wanted to direct folks to a *possible* solution.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a lot of problems here as mentioned in the comments but I recently had a problem with browser compatibility and the solution was to use [polyfills](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html). Uncomment the following lines:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

And run your application. It should be working down to `IE10` at least it worked out for us. Based on the error message it is likely to work for You as well.

Comment: Tried uncommenting pollyfils, Still getting same issue.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50070943/1253298

Answer (score 0):

Try to load jQuery [polyfills](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/polyfill/) from assets:

in index.html's head:

```
  <script src="assets/...">
```

My take is to try at least https://plugins.jquery.com/webshims/